# How do i install Qubes OS onto a USB?

Tags: linux, installation, liveusb

I cannot install qubes onto my harddrive as it has my main windows OS on it and is not easily switched out, and qubes FAQ warns not to do this anyways. I would like to install onto a USB drive instead but cannot find any information on how to do this, can anyone explain the process?

This is the OS page https://www.qubes-os.org/

Answer (score 2):

Use Universal USB Installer on your Windows machine and select your Qubes OS .iso image, as well as your flash drive directory to install it on.

After that, boot from your USB drive.

Link: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/